# Visual Studio C# - How to properly create content

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, opentk

I started using C# with OpenTK to move on from XNA since it's now obsolete.

I've replicated most of XNA's functionality now (Graphics, Audio, Text, Input), but the only part I'm missing is around content management.

At the moment my content has to be manually dropped into the same folder as the .exe, since that's where it gets referenced from. I access it by writing constant strings in for the relative position for assets from the .exe. This means when I move from Debug to Release, I have to copy the content files across manually.

Ideally what I want is for my assets folder to build automatically into the same folder as my .exe, with my assets folder being part of my project. What's the best way to do this? (I prefer not to have a separate content project, unless that's best practice).

If it's also straightforward, how can I "protect" my assets like XNA did? Are there open source libraries for this?

I'm using VS2013 Express if that's relevant.

Comment: Copy to output property of project items should solve copying content to output... Or I missed the problem altogether?

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I want. Where is that option?

Comment: OK so I found it (right click on an item and select properties). Is there an equivalent for folders? They don't have the same option in "Properties" which is where I had been looking. I have a lot of assets within several folders and it would be much better to be able to do on many files at once. Or can I default files that are added to particular folders?

Comment: No option for folders. You can hand-edit .csproj to include files with wildcard (like "Big*.jpg" instead of "Big1.jpg"...) and set property that way.

Comment: I use a post-build command on the project to copy all the needed content to the output folder like that: xcopy "$(ProjectDir)Data" "$(TargetDir)Data" /E /R /K /Y /I /D /H